# Error while passing string as function argument in python

Tags: python, string, function

I have a python code:

```
for i in edges_list:
        i = i.to_string()
        i = i.replace("->", ",")
        i = i.replace("[", ",")
        i = i.replace("];" , "")
        G1.add_edge(i)
```

When I execute it, I get the error: `TypeError: add_edge() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)`

i is of the form `5 , 15  , color="#0000FF"`
If I did G1.add_edge(5 , 15  , color="#0000FF") I'm not getting any error. However, when I pass it as string I get that error.

I tried `i.split('"\'')` bu it didn't resolve the problem. What to do?

Comment: We can't help without knowing what `G1` is here.

Comment: This should do :

    G1.add_adge(*tuple(i.split('"\'')))

Comment: @Loïc: right, this isn't about the type error but about passing in multiple arguments from a sequence.

Comment: @Loïc, I still get the same error after trying it.

Comment: maybe : G1.add_adge(*i.split('"\''))